# SpringBoot executes the interceptor multiple times in one request. What causes this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to add an interceptor to limit the user's access frequency, but I found that my interceptor will be called multiple times, causing frequency control problems.

Register interceptor:

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")
@Configuration
public class InterceptorRegistrar implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final String errorPath;

    @Autowired
    public InterceptorRegistrar(
            @NotNull Environment environment
    ) {
        this.errorPath = environment.getProperty("server.error.path", "/error");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(@NotNull InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        final String[] excludePaths = {"/ping", this.errorPath};
        InterceptorRegistration registration;

        registration = registry.addInterceptor(new FrequencyInterceptor());
        registration.addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns(excludePaths);
    }
}
```

Frequency control interceptor:

```java
import com.zhiweidata.rssarticlesimilarity.util.HttpUtil;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;

import static com.zhiweidata.rssarticlesimilarity.containers.NoMagicalValue.APPID_KEY;
import static com.zhiweidata.rssarticlesimilarity.entity.vo.ResponseMessageVO.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
import static com.zhiweidata.rssarticlesimilarity.entity.vo.ResponseMessageVO.UNAUTHORIZED;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;
import static java.util.Objects.isNull;

@Slf4j
@SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")
public class FrequencyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final Map<String, Long> frequency = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, @NotNull Object handler) throws Exception {
        String appid = request.getParameter(APPID_KEY);
        log.info("url {}, appid {}", request.getServletPath(), appid);

        if (isBlank(appid)) {
            HttpUtil.write(response, UNAUTHORIZED);
            return false;
        }

        Long access = this.frequency.get(appid);
        long value;
        if (isNull(access)) {
            this.frequency.put(appid, System.currentTimeMillis());
            log.info("ok");
            return true;
        } else if ((value = System.currentTimeMillis() - access) < 100) {
            log.info("Last visit interval {}ms", value);
            HttpUtil.write(response, SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
            this.frequency.put(appid, System.currentTimeMillis());
            return false;
        } else {
            this.frequency.put(appid, System.currentTimeMillis());
            log.info("ok");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Execution request:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:8080/rss-article-similarity/original-article/similar-articles\?originalUrl\=https://mobile.time-weekly.com/v2/articles/B3OAQB\&appid\=61aece263575d95d4dd8b888\&seed\=9WIBZPddQ8\&sign\=157525BCB4D7EC08ACAED8FA32DBB3F8 -v
```

console log:

```sh
2021-12-07 17:38:53.971 INFO  100928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.z.r.interceptor.FrequencyInterceptor   preHandle                      38    : url /original-article/similar-articles, appid 61aece263575d95d4dd8b888
2021-12-07 17:38:53.973 INFO  100928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.z.r.interceptor.FrequencyInterceptor   preHandle                      58    : ok
2021-12-07 17:38:54.001 INFO  100928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.z.r.interceptor.FrequencyInterceptor   preHandle                      38    : url /original-article/original-article/similar-articles, appid 61aece263575d95d4dd8b888
2021-12-07 17:38:54.003 INFO  100928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.z.r.interceptor.FrequencyInterceptor   preHandle                      52    : Last visit interval 30ms
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2021:17:38:54 +0800] "GET /rss-article-similarity/original-article/similar-articles?originalUrl=https://mobile.time-weekly.com/v2/articles/B3OAQB&appid=61aece263575d95d4dd8b888&seed=9WIBZPddQ8&sign=157525BCB4D7EC08ACAED8FA32DBB3F8 HTTP/1.1" 503 81
```

After many attempts, I found:

1. The originalUrl parameter is not carried in the request, and the interceptor can run normally. Whether it is spring.profiles.active=dev or spring.profiles.active=test.
2. spring.profiles.active=test and the original URL parameter is included in the request, the interceptor will be executed multiple times, resulting in invalid frequency control.
3. spring.profiles.active=dev and the original URL parameter in the request, the interceptor executes normally.

My several tests only modify the configuration of spring.profiles.active, and there is no change in other configuration items.

Comment: Apparently you are doing some rewriting/forwarding the request, leading to a new request.

Comment: @M.Deinum No, redirection is not used in my project. The only internal redirection is /error, but I excluded it when registering the interceptor.

Comment: I stated forwarding, the fact that you don't doesn't mean there isn't an other part of the application that does. Looking at the URLs it actually does that. As you get a different URL.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can be sure that this kind of forwarding does not come from my project code, nor is it related to SpringBoot used in the entire project, but it is not a framework officially developed by SpringBoot. Why only spring.profiles.active=test with a parameter like originalUrl will this kind of forwarding appear?

Comment: Again I'm not saying it comes from your project code but something that is in your project and that isn't enabled when `dev` profile is active. So something is enabled which does rewriting/forwading. Also why areyou implementing this yourself instead of using something like `Resillience4j`. Your interceptor also does 2 things security and rate-limiting. But that is something different.